# Best design practice when one python method passes most of its arguments to another method

Tags: architecture, python, api

My code has 2 python methods defined, `m1` and `m2`. `m1` receives 6 arguments - p1,p2,p3...p6. It uses `p1` in its own code, but passes `p2`-`p6` to `m2`. Is there a recommended programming style here to prevent the definition of `m1` from getting too verbose?

Is this a good scenario to use `**kwargs` in?

Comment: Just as a general comment, there's rarely (if ever) a best way to do something.  There are typically a lot of (perhaps infinite) bad ways to do something and a handful of good ways.

Comment: I would see this as a code smell, and the appropriate way of fixing is not applying some rule or recipe, but analyzing and fixing the stink.

Comment: Are m1 and m2 always linked like this?  Or is m2 sometimes called separately, without calling m1 first?

Comment: @JohnGordon As of now they are linked like this but it is possible that in the future m2 could be called from a context besides m1.

Comment: kwargs *could* be helpful but it also makes code hard to follow as actual parameters are hidden in deeper layers.  It’s powerful but don’t reach for it “just” to clean up m1’s signature vis a vis m2, that’s not doing the callers any real favors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there a recommended programming style here to prevent the definition of m1 from getting too verbose?

Sort of. The style is called *"working in small iterations, doing regular refactorings, ideally supported by unit tests"*.

Fowler's [refactoring catalogue](https://refactoring.com/catalog/) contains some refactorings which can help to reduce the number of parameters, [introducing parameter object](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) is one of them. Another technique which is sometimes applicable is to [combine functions into a class](https://refactoring.com/catalog/combineFunctionsIntoClass.html), so the class provides member attributes which can be accessed from every member function without being explicitly passed around.

Still, from anonymous names like `m1` or `p1`,`p2`, ... it is impossible to say which of those refactorings make most sense for your specific situation (if any), or how to apply them exactly.

Comment: Indeed. The parameter object shouldn't just be assumed to be p2-p6. Look at what they are and ask if they really go together. Might be p2 & p3 go well together and while p4-p6 don't go well with them they also go well with each other. So fine, make two parameter objects. But don't just blindly think about what needs what. Think about what these things are.

Comment: Without examples showing the techniques, this looks dangerously close to a link-only answer.

Comment: @J.Mini I think that we can't give anymore than this as the question needs to provide more details. See the last paragraph of the answer

Answer (score 5):

Create a data object with those grouped parameters. And then pass the data object between functions.

Comment: I've heard this called a "Parameter Bag", though there is probably a different name for it.

Comment: I've heard this derogatively called a "big ball of state"

Comment: Applied unthinkingly, this is strictly worse than passing multiple parameters. The grouped parameters **must** have some semantic connection besides being the parameters to `m2`.

Answer (score 2):

Your description does not make it clear what m2 is. But if m2 is some kind of callback method, you could pass in a lambda where all the parameters p2-p6 are already bound to the passed in method.

In a way thats a variant on parameter objects.

Comment: …or in OOP style, pass an instance of a class with `m2` as a parameter-less method and all the argument values as fields of that object